# What excatly are the risks of not installing Windows Security Update at all?

Tags: windows, security, windows-update

We've been told that you should always install Windows Security Updates, but what **exactly** would happen if you don't? Can modern versions of Windows (7 and later) be infected simply by connected to the internet? (using default "Public" network profile, which if I understand correctly means no open ports by default)

Let's say I have an old machine or a virtual machine that I don't want or can't install Windows Update due to various reasons, **if I make sure to only run program that I know and trust**, what are the risks of not installing any Windows Update at all?

Answer (score 3):

Consider it the equivalent of locking a door with an old-fashioned lock and then *never checking it ever again* to see if someone's managed to break in.

You don't know if the computer's safe, because no-one is ever going to check that lock again. Since the system went unsupported, people will have been making a concerted effort to find ways in, that would go unnoticed by the user. In the normal scheme of things, there are people constantly checking & testing for vulnerabilities. Once found, these are reported, fixed & patched in all vulnerable OSes.
No-one is ever going to do that for Windows 7… so whatever way hackers may find to break that old-fashioned lock, the only way you ever discover it is when something goes badly wrong.

The advice, therefore, isn't really to not use the old OS, but to never allow it on the internet. If you can load it with OS & software from before support was ended, then you are *likely* to be safe, if no further exposure to the outside world is allowed.

Comment: Correct.  Although, I cringe with the analogy of locks, as they tend to offer only only a hair above superficial protection, at best.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows operating system and the myriad of programs that come integrated with it are a very complex suit of software. Complex software like that will always have some bugs. Those bugs might have exploitable security vulnerabilities. Sometimes these vulnerabilities can be exploited remotely to make your computer do things you didn't tell it to do.

What happens when such an exploit gets discovered?

1. The person discovering it has to make a moral decision: Shut up, tell Microsoft before someone else finds it, or abuse it themselves for fame, fun and/or profit.
2. Regardless of what decision the person makes, Microsoft will sooner or later find out about that vulnerability. Either because they are told, or because they notice people exploiting it.
3. Microsoft will create and critical security update to fix the vulnerability and release it through the Windows update service.
4. Most people will download and apply that security update.
5. Nefarious people will download the security update and reverse-engineer it to find out what vulnerability it actually fixes, how it works and how it could be exploited.
6. Those nefarious people will then create malware to exploit that vulnerability in order to turn anyone's computer who didn't bother to install the update into a [botnet zombie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet). Which they can then abuse for various illegal but profitable endeavors.

Do you want your computer to become part of a hacker's botnet? If not, then better install the security updates.